# Unable to read properties file after creating it

Tags: java

I am creating a properties file and putting into my classpath folder Resources.
When I tried to read this file , i am not getting the expected result. i am getting the result of the previous values printed instead of the property values set now.
My class file is as follows :

```
public class App {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    PrintWriter output = null;

    try {

        output = new PrintWriter("Resources/config.properties");

        // set the properties value
        prop.setProperty("database", "localhost");
        prop.setProperty("dbuser", "mkyong");
        prop.setProperty("dbpassword", "password");

        // save properties to project root folder
        prop.store(output, null);
        if(output!=null) {
            System.out.println("Output");

            output.close();

        }

    } catch (IOException io) {
        io.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (output != null) {

                output.close();

        }

    }

    Properties prop1 = new Properties();
    BufferedInputStream input = null;

    try {

        String filename = "config.properties";
        input =  (BufferedInputStream) AppCPLoad.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
        if(input==null){
                System.out.println("Sorry, unable to find " + filename);
            return;
        }

        //load a properties file from class path, inside static method

        prop1.load(input);

            //get the property value and print it out
            System.out.println(prop1.getProperty("database"));
            System.out.println(prop1.getProperty("dbuser"));
            System.out.println(prop1.getProperty("dbpassword"));
            if(input!=null) {
                System.out.println("Input");
                input.close();
            }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        if(input!=null){
            try {
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Why dont you use. FileInputStream any specific reason you are fetching a file from your folder. why dont you use FileInputStream while fetching.

Comment: Once use this line in your script and you will get to know the reason.... System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"))

Answer (score 0):

When you run the program, the properties file is loaded and the values are read. After you rewrite the properties file, that doesn't mean that the properties you have loaded already have be to rewritten. *You need to reload the properties file and re-read the values*. You are looking for an implementation like [ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html)